# jqGrid addChildNode bug when calling the function

Tags: jqgrid

I seem to have a bug with jqGrid and the addChildNode command.  Whenever I use something like the following

```
$('#grid').jqGrid("addChildNode", "6", "2", data);
```

I get no new row but the root gets another expand arrow icon, sort of like this:

```
▼ ▼ Row name
```

"6" is the new ID field value and 2 is the ID field of the parent (not rowid).  The idPrefix is "loc" so as not to have numbers as ID values.

If I repeat the command, I just get another arrow down and still no new rows.

Using the latest version of jqGrid, v5.3.2.  Evaluating to switch over from the free fork.

Comment: Can you please post the jqGrid setup and some test data? The best will be if you have online example. Thank you.

Comment: I found the bug, it's when you have idPrefix set that causes the bug.

Comment: I think it starts in line 875 in grid.treegrid.js { var prow = $($t).jqGrid('getInd', parentid); } as parentid is not the rowid but the unique ID field